# Screen recording on iPad 1: what are the options without jailbreak?

Tags: ipad, ios, screen-capture

AppStore requests a demo video for my app, but at the moment all I have is an iPad 1 with iOS 5 on it. They don't accept a video recorded in a simulator.

Buying a newer iPad is one obvious option, unless there are others.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a Mac?, since iOS do not allow screen recording.

Comment: Not sure you need a video recorder or just screen captures.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I suppose what the Review Team needs is a screen capture.

Comment: Then you have your answer, just take a series of screen captures.