# Recording iPad screen using QuickTime

Tags: ipad, audio, screen-capture, quicktime, microphone

I need to record a demo on my iPad's screen where I narrate what's going on but I also want the sounds from the iPad to be in the video. It seems that choosing the Mac Built-in Mic option causes only my voice to be in the video while choosing the iPad Mic option cause only the sounds from the iPad to be in the video. What can I do to put both in the video?

Comment: In imovie you can just paste another sound file under your recordings, it is more work but it is quite easy and gives a nice result.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157727/ and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145495/

Answer (score 1):

Best way is probably to use [AirServer](http://airserver.com). You just mirror to your PC/Mac and record the iOS device's screen to disk. You can also go live on youtube with AirServer.